# Lucene index inside of a database

Tags: java, database, oracle, lucene

is it possible to do this?  i have an oracle db and wondering if storing an index inside may be the most efficient way to go vs storing the index on a file system.  has anyone done this before?  is it possible with lucene version 3.x?

Comment: Why? Oracle already has it's own internal indexing. Secondly lucene is a file based indexing technology designed to be external to your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using the Lucene Directory interface, but it's not easy. Many people have tried, but you get terrible performance. The reason is that to execute a search, you have to read the entire index (or segment) out of the database as a blob and run the search on top of it. Very inefficient.